# Strategy to Complete 1.6 km in 14 minutes

Tags: running

I am 24 years old having 5'5" (165 cm) height and weight 52 kg. I want to complete 1.6 km in 14 minutes till 5th July. How can I complete this target within the stipulated time? What should be the best strategy to do so?

Comment: It might be worth to add your current time on that distance

Comment: The average walking speed of pedestrians is said to be around 5km/h, _i.e._ 1.2km per 15min. - maybe you already hit your target without being aware of :)

Comment: Something is seriously wrong here; 1.6km is an odd distance to target, and the target time for this distance seems very slow, given your age and lack of disclosed injuries. Could you mention what total distance you are looking at? Also, by some chance, are you looking at running 1.6miles in 14 min? That would be a typical running target for amateurs.

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy would be to build some cardiovascular endurance. 1.6 km in 14 minutes is not very fast at all, a consistent brisk walking pace would allow you to achieve this goal.